# VBA for Access trouble picking routine to run

Tags: vba, ms-access, module

I’m working on a project in access with a series of existing modules. There’s amain module that runs the whole thing, but often there are errors and to troubleshoot sometimes i want to pick a specific subroutine and run that by itself. The problem is, sometimes when i click run>run sub/userform sometimes it gives me a list of subroutines to pick from and sometimes it just runs the whole thing and i can never tell which it’s going to do before i click it. Does anyone know why this could happen? Is it where I’m putting my cursor or something?

Comment: parameterized subs cannot be run directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now this works?

well, any code in a code module? You can place your cursor in that code, or even in the debug window, just type in the name of the routine. So, F5 to run the code, or you can as noted even call the code in the routine from the debug window.

eg:

Call MyTestSub("John")

Or if the routine does not have any parameters, then just type into the debug window this:

```
MyTestSub
```

HOWEVER!!!

If you open code for a form? Then you can't use F5 to run that code, and if you do, then your get that prompt. The reason for this is rather complex, but a "form" represents what we call a "class object". And you can't just "run" such code, you a have to first create a instance of that class. And even more complex?

Well in theory, you can actually ahve the SAME form open 5 times!!! (and have 5 instances of the form running! So F5, or even just typing in the sub name DOES NOT work for a class module, and that includes code inside of the form.

So, how to debug such code? Well, in most cases, you have to launch the form, and then in code behind, set a break-point. Now go click the button, or whatever.

You can also in theory call + run the code in a form, and you would do it this way:

```
Call Forms("Test").Mytest
```

but, the form would have to be open. So, you can't just run code inside of a class module, or  forms code module. They are "special" and work different from a standard code module. As a result, F5 to run such code does not work. In fact, the form has to be loaded first. But, even then, hitting F5 inside of forms code modules does not work. You can put in break points, and single step code (and often form events can make that debug process quite a challenge).